# Can I remove all Mail Merge settings from an Office document and start again?

Tags: microsoft-office

I have Office 2010 documents which mail merge from an Excel spreadsheet. If I update the spreadsheet and try to repeat the mail merge, it doesn't pick up changes (even if I go to Select Recipients > Use Existing List again).

The workaround is to have a copy of the document before any recipient list is selected and fork it each time I merge. Obviously this isn't satisfactory.

It's driving me crazy. Can I reset the mail merge settings so that changes can be picked up?